# The number of linearly dependent subsets of size 3 with entries from $\{1,-1,0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

> Let $S$ be a set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ whose coordinates are in $\{-1,1,0\}$. How many $3$ element subsets of $S$ are linearly dependent?

---

There are totally $27$ possible vectors. If we fix origin as one vector, then we have $\binom{26}{2}$ choices for the remaining two vectors. Since we can choose a vector and its negative, among all sets having no origin, we have $13*24$ choices to obtain a linearly dependent set.

I can see that there are some vectors that are on a plane, but I don't know how to exhaustively count them! How do we solve this problem?

Comment: Program a computer to run through all three-element subsets. There are fewer than 3,000 of them, it should take no time at all.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: The question asks for linearly dependent sets.

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you were doing. You are right that you can use the zero vector and any other pair of vectors, and then add on the count of all other triples that lie on a single plane through the origin. I don't see an easy way to count them just yet. It's either a lot of case work (classifying triplets according to how many corner/edge/facecentre vectors they have and using symmetry), or determining the kinds of planes through the origin (those with 8 non-origin points, those with other numbers of points).

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the points of the cube $[-1,0,1]^3$. It is enough to count the number of sets $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ such that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are collinear or non-collinear but contained in a plane through the origin. Let us focus on the collinear sets first. On each face of the cube we have $3+3+2$ collinear sets (rows, columns, diagonals), so a total of $48-12=36$ collinear sets on the surface. If a collinear set contains two points on distinct faces it has to contain an interior point by convexity. There is a single interior point, namely the origin, so there are $\frac{27-1}{2}=13$ collinear sets through the origin and $49$ collinear sets.

Now we just need to count the non-collinear sets on a plane through the origin. $\binom{26}{2}-13$ triples of this kind contain the origin. Let us assume from now on that our triples do not contain the origin. $13\cdot 24$ non-collinear triples contain a couple of antipodal points. Now it might be useful to classify the points on the surface according to their distance from the origin:

- $6$ points, the centers of the faces, have distance $1$ (**F**, two coordinates equal zero)
- $12$ points, the midpoints of the edges, have distance $\sqrt{2}$ (**E**, one coordinate equals zero)
- $8$ points, the vertices, have distance $\sqrt{3}$ (**V**, all coordinates differ from zero)

then to classify the CPNA (coplanar not antipodal) triples according to the number of elements they have in $F,E,V$. There are no CPNA triples with $\geq 2$ elements in $F$ or in $V$. There are $24$ CPNA triples with exactly one vertex. It only remains to count how many CPNA triples have $0$ elements in $V$, i.e. the number of CPNA triples in a cuboctahedron. These triples are made by two elements in $E$ and one element in $F$, or three elements in $E$. The $FEE$ CPNA triples are $12$: they are necessarily made by the center of a face and two opposite midpoints of edges on the opposite face. The $EEE$ CPNA triples lie on hexagonal sections of the cube, like the one given by $x+y+z=0$. There are four hexagonal sections of this kind (as many as the diameters of the cube), so there are $4\left(\binom{6}{3}-12\right)=32$ $EEE$ CPNA triples.

If I have not miscounted something, there should be $741$ linearly dependent triples.

Comment: Why can't there be noncollinear linearly dependent vectors?

Comment: Right, I need to fix this.

Comment: I think one gets more than $429$ linearly dependent $3$-subsets just by counting cases where one of the vectors is the zero vector along with cases where all vectors are nonzero with two being opposite vectors. And this does not cover all cases.

Comment: The case in which there are opposite non-zero vectors is accounted for, now I included also the (trivial) cases in which one of the vectors is the zero vector.

Comment: Dear Jack, You say "There are no CPNA triples with ≥2 elements in  or in ". But (1,0,0), (0,0,1) and (1,0,1) is CNPA with more than 2 elements in V.